# Salesforce Site - Access error - Authorization Required - unable to retrieve object - VF Page

Tags: visualforce, custom-object, force.com-sites, standardcontroller

I had a site setup which just hosts a single VF page. This page is an e-ticket which needs to be accessable publicly. It was working fine about a year ago until i revisted it last month and now I'm getting an authorization error.
Bear in mind i havent made any changes to anything, it broke on it's own.
I've double checked access settings to make sure all fields can be accessed by guest profile etc.

Now i've cloned the page, stripped evrything out and just put one field in there to test. It still shows the error.

[image]

Has anyone else experienced this problem or know what the workaround is?

This has affected all of our sites as well, not just this one. I noticed all our sites were all modified by an automated process early 2020. I don't know if this has anything to do with it.

[image]

Example page code

```
    <apex:page renderAs="pdf" standardController="Registration_Subscription__c"  applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" applyBodyTag="false" >
    
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello World!</p>
<p>{!Registration_Subscription__c.Contact_Name__c}</p>
</body> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: The security model of a 'guest' user was changed by Salesforce, most recently in Winter 20.  https://www.learnexperiencecloud.com/s/article/Guest-User-Record-Access-Development-Best-Practices is a good reference

Comment: Thanks your a life saver! I missed that release update! Followed your link and set up sharing rules on the objects I needed accessing for the guest user profile. Worked straight away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just needed to set up sharing rules for guest user profiles on the related objects
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/security_sharing_rules_guest.htm

Here's what my rule looked like:

[image]